# What is the correct way to reuse a aiohttp ClientSession() object?

Tags: python-asyncio, aiohttp

I would like to verify whether the code I have created is an appropriate and effective way to reuse a `aiohttp.ClientSession()` object.

```
from asyncio import tasks
import aiohttp
import asyncio
import time

websites = ['http://corndog.io/', 'https://onesquareminesweeper.com/', 'https://checkboxolympics.com/', 'https://binarypiano.com/', 'https://alwaysjudgeabookbyitscover.com/', 'https://cant-not-tweet-this.com/', 'https://cursoreffects.com/', 'http://eelslap.com/', 'https://smashthewalls.com/', 'https://thatsthefinger.com/']



# function to regroup a larger list of tasks to "smaller groups"
def feeder(a_list, unit):
    list_length = len(a_list)
    groups = []
    a = 0
    z = unit
    while a < list_length:
        groups.append(a_list[a:z])
        a += unit
        z += unit
    return groups

# function to create a list of co-routine object from each "smaller group" for the "gather()" function
def create_tasks(session, job_slice):
    co_routine_objects  = []
    for i in job_slice:
        co_routine_objects.append(session.get(i, ssl = False))
    return co_routine_objects

async def main(job_list):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        for job_slice in job_list:
            tasks = create_tasks(session, job_slice)
            responses = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
            for item in responses:
                data.append(await item.text())
                print(len(data))
    

job_list = feeder(websites, 3)
data = []


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main(job_list))
```

What I tried to achieve:

1 - Take a list of website URLS

2 - Regroup the URLS within a list of lists

3 - Create a synchronous function which has the role to return a list of co-routine objects built from an item within the list of lists created in the previous step

4 - Create an asynchronous function which has the role to CREATE AND KEEP OPEN A REUSABLE AIOHTTP CLIENT SESSION OBJECT then post a list of GET requests returned by the "create tasks" function all at once

5 - Take the next "group" of links from the regrouped list and feed the GET requests through the SAME CLIENT SESSION THAT WAS CREATED IN STEP 4

I am in the process of learning to work with the "aiohttp" and the "async" module and while the code above is functioning I am not sure if it is functioning as I intended (see above) or if there is a better, or more efficient/faster way to implement/structure the code.

Could someone please confirm that:

- only one session object is used
- the session object created is kept open and reused throughout the execution of the code and not "opened and closed" with each iteration

Also if you see a way to restructure the sample code that would allow to obtain data in a faster more efficient way  from the URLS using AIOHTTP/ASYNCIO, please highlight it.

Many thanks.